# Pascal double value is not exact, how to fix this?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have been solving a programming challenge in UVA and got this problem, which is REALLY strange. Here is the flawed code:

```
program WTF;
begin
  WriteLn(Trunc(2.01 * 100));
  ReadLn();
end.
```

Obviously, I need to get `201` as `Integer`, but I get `200`, this happens because Double somehow doesn't store the exact value... It's `2.01 = 2.00(9)` for reasons unbeknownst to me, can someone explain this and provide a solution?

Edit: Yet, I figgured that using `Round()` instead of `Trunc()` fixes this... But still, why wouldn't `Trunc()` work?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: If you want to to get `200` you wouldn't use `Trunc`. With `Trunc` you intentionally truncate the significant digits that would have rounded to `201` before it converted to integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Double` stores numbers of the form s*2<sup>p</sup> where s and p are integers. The number 2.01 is not of the form s*2<sup>p</sup> for any integers s, p so it cannot be stored exactly in a `Double`.

The solution here is to round `2.01 * 100` to the nearest integer instead of truncating it. Although `2.01` is not exactly 2.01, it is only a little bit below. Rounding to the nearest integer would result in 201.

---

Note that if by `2.00(9)` you mean `2.0099999999…` repeating indefinitely, then `2.00(9)`is **not** the `Double` you get when you write `2.01`. The nearest `Double` to the real 2.01, and the number you got, is `2.0099999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625`. It is of the form s * 2<sup>p</sup>: 9052235251014696 * 2<sup>-52</sup>

Comment: Huh, didn't know that. :) Thank you, I' pretty sure I had this problem occur some long time ago, yeah, rounding did fix the problem.